# "message": "MongoServerError: unknown top level operator: $${match}price$${match}

Tags: query-string

> "message": "MongoServerError: unknown top level operator: $${match}price$${match}. If you have a field name that starts with a '$' symbol, consider using $getField or $setField."

I intended to get all products from a MongoDB database using Mongoose, with the ability to filter results based on the query parameters in the request.

This line  `queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt|)\b/g, (match) => '$${match}');`, is supposed to replace instances of `gte`, `gt`, `lte`, and `lt` in `queryStr` with their MongoDB counterparts.

However, there seems to be an issue, because I keep getting the error message above, while trying to make use of MongoDB’s query operators.

Answer (score 0):

A friend just sent me an article which says, javaScript template literals are denoted by backticks (`), not single or double quotes. So, the correct line should be:

`queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, (match) =>` $${match}`);`

Not this
`queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt|)\b/g, (match) => '$${match}');`

This will correctly replace the comparison operators in queryStr with their MongoDB counterparts. Thanks everyone.